# Upvoting my other account's question by accident

Tags: support, upvotes, accounts, duplicate-accounts

I created another account purely for Stack Overflow whereas I use this one on Stack Exchange subdomains. I asked a question on my new account on Stack Overflow and then signed into this one.

As there is no way to be logged in to two accounts at the same time (just realized this now) I was monitoring my other account's question and tried clicking upvote (thinking I was still logged in the new account as it was showing my old account in the top-right corner). The page refreshed, my new account's question got upvoted but from THIS account. I know this is against the rules and I instantly downvoted it back.

Should I be concerned?

It's a sincere mistake on my part and it's not something I would ever practice.

Comment: I'm not a moderator, but since you reversed your actions, I doubt that any harm should come your way

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, thank you for your reply, that made me less anxious!

Comment: I have never seen this specific situation on meta, but usually mods are reasonable people and give the benefit of the doubt. If this is the first time, there hasn't been warnings, and you reversed the vote right away, I'd say the worst that'll happen is a friendly reminder (don't take this for cash, I am not a mod)

Comment: @Patrice Thank you for your reassurance, I'm gonna wait and see what the mod says!

Comment: Other than not voting for the other account (or at least undoing accidental votes), having a second account is fine as long as you don’t use it to do things you couldn’t do with your current account. That’s broader than just “don’t vote”; also don’t use an extra account to work around system limitations like how many questions you can post in a day, or cast multiple flags, etc. You get the idea. Extra accounts are fine as long as you only ever use them to do things your first account can do without extras.

Comment: `I instantly downvoted it back`:-- No need to "downvote"; just click "upvote" button again to cancel the upvote cast by accident. As you clicked downvote instead, it is being counted as a vote. If it does not allow you now to do that, as too much time is passed; slightly edit the question to make it happen.

Comment: @AmitJoshi that's exactly what I did, sorry for being unclear :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

No, that vote and unvote activity probably isn't even tracked anywhere other than internal logs which we don't have access to. As far as we're concerned, it's practically as if you never voted on your question by accident in the first place. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @Shibalicious: No problem. BTW, I assume you mean you canceled your upvote rather than changed it to a downvote, since you don't actually have the ability to cast downvotes yet.

Comment: exactly that, my bad!